# Schrodinger-like derivation of the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation

One can derive the Schrodinger equation as follows:

$U(\delta t)|\psi(t)\rangle  = (I - i \delta tH)|\psi(t)\rangle = |\psi(t+\delta t)\rangle  \rightarrow i\frac{|\psi(t+\delta t) - |\psi(t)\rangle}{\delta t} = i\frac{\partial |\psi(t)\rangle}{\partial t} = H|\psi(t)\rangle$

see this answer [enter link description here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208817/747)

---

I am now interested in deriving the Dirac equation using the same methodology.

My idea is instead of $U=e^{-itH/\hbar}$, I would start with this:

$$
G=\exp -i \frac{mc}{4\hbar}(t\gamma_0+x\gamma_1+y\gamma_2+z\gamma_3)
$$

Now, I apply the same method as the Schrodinger equation (one for each variable):

$$
G(\delta t, x,y ,z) | \psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle=(I-i\frac{mc}{4\hbar}\gamma_0 \delta t)|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle =|\psi(t+\delta t,x,y,z)\rangle \\
G(t, \delta x,y ,z) | \psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle=(I-i\frac{mc}{4\hbar}\gamma_1 \delta x)|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle = |\psi(t,x+\delta x ,y,z)\rangle\\
G(t, x, \delta y ,z) | \psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle=(I-i\frac{mc}{4\hbar}\gamma_2 \delta y)|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle = |\psi(t,x,y+\delta y,z)\rangle\\
G(t, x,  y , \delta z) | \psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle=(I-i\frac{mc}{4\hbar}\gamma_3 \delta z)|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle = |\psi(t,x, y,z + \delta z)\rangle
$$

Each one of them produces a Schrodinger-like equation for its respective component:

$$
\gamma_0 i \frac{\partial |\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle }{\partial t} = \frac{mc}{4\hbar}|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle\\
\gamma_1 i\frac{\partial |\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle }{\partial x} = \frac{mc}{4\hbar}|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle\\
\gamma_2 i\frac{\partial |\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle }{\partial y} = \frac{mc}{4\hbar}|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle\\
\gamma_3 i\frac{\partial |\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle }{\partial z} = \frac{mc}{4\hbar}|\psi(t,x,y,z)\rangle
$$

Finally, I add them together and I get the Dirac equation

$$
i \hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - mc \psi =0
$$

---

Does any of this works? Can we understand the Dirac equation as a 4 parameter evolution of $G$, which would be an extension of the one-parameter evolution of U for the Schrodinger equation?

Comment: Note that this would imply something much stronger than the Dirac equation, namely your four isolated equations independently all holding. On that basis I would be extremely skeptical that this $G$ can be given a similar meaning to $U$.

Answer (score -1):

Usually it is done the other way around: the initary operator is derived from the equation (Schrödinger or Dirac). Obviously, the converse is true - it is sufficient to note that
$$
\partial_t U(t)=\frac{-iH}{\hbar}U(t)
$$ and that
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t)|\psi(0)\rangle.
$$